# Выбранный по умолчанию элемент ListView

Tags: android, listview

Есть ListView содержащий, к примеру, список покупок. При тапе на определенный элемент он подсвечивается. Как установить выбранный по умолчанию элемент? Чтобы пользователь перешел на новую активити, увидел список покупок и выбранный по умолчанию элемент?

Comment: Вопрос не ясен - что значит "по умолчанию выбранный в другой активити"? Вы не знаете как передавать значения меж активити?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вопрос не в этом. я хочу чтобы был подсвечен по умолчанию любой элемент, переход между активити тут не играет никакой роли. Чтобы, к примеру, пользователь при нажатии на кнопку "список покупок" попадал на новую активити с ListView, в котором уже один элемент выбранный по умолчанию, и, соответственно подсвеченный.

Comment: Т.е. вы не знаете как подсветить?...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, как подсветить я знаю, а вот как назначить посдвеченный по умолчанию элемент, то есть ВЫБРАННЫЙ по умолчанию, вот это уже не знаю как

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, нужно поменять `choiceMode`,
указать цвет в `listSelector`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="твой цвет"/>
```

И в OnCreate после инициализации списка:

```
list.setItemChecked( 0, true ); \\ 0 это позиция в списке, отсчёт ведётся с 0.
```

И еще можно указать селектор:

*item_background_selector.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_activated="true"
    android:color="#0094CE">
  </item>

  <item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:color="#0094CE">
  </item>

  <item android:state_pressed="false"
    android:color="#ACD52B">
  </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Наверное не `list.setItemChecked( 0, true );`, а пояснить хотя бы, что ноль здесь не просто так, а позиция в списке, которую нужно выделить (в данном случае первый элемент списка, так как отсчет позиций начинается с нуля)

Comment: Точно, спасибо, я как-то не подумал.